# Limit of square root of sequence given value of limit of original sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, limits-without-lhopital

Suppose that $x_n\ge0$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0\in\mathbb{R}$.  Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{x_0}$.

In this context, a sequence $x_n$ converging to a constant $\alpha$ is given by:

$$\exists\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\ge N:|x_n-\alpha|<\epsilon$$

However, I'm struggling to prove this in a more abstract form; when I have a simpler algebraic expression fo $x_n$, I know the process, but I'm confused how to show it in general using the above definition.

Comment: You know, for this kind of a problem, it is best that you do what you know already in the question itself. If you know the process , describe what you know, If you do not know it in general, describe the case that you know, and tell us why you think that case is not applicable here. Also, observe funnily the first two words of the first three lines of this comment are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

The case that $x_{0}=0$ is left to OP.

For the case that $x_{0}>0$, find some $N_{1}$ such that $|x_{n}-x_{0}|<\dfrac{x_{0}}{2}$ for all $n\geq N_{1}$, then $x_{n}\geq x_{0}-\dfrac{x_{0}}{2}>\dfrac{x_{0}}{2}$ for all such $n$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, find some $N_{2}$ such that $|x_{n}-x_{0}|<\dfrac{3\sqrt{x_{0}}}{2}\cdot\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_{2}$.

For all $n\geq N_{1}+N_{2}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\left|\sqrt{x_{n}}-\sqrt{x_{0}}\right|&=\dfrac{|x_{n}-x_{0}|}{\sqrt{x_{n}}+\sqrt{x_{0}}}\\
&<\dfrac{|x_{n}-x_{0}|}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x_{0}}}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{x_{0}}}\\
&<\dfrac{|x_{n}-x_{0}|}{\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+1\right)\sqrt{x_{0}}}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{x_{0}}}\cdot|x_{n}-x_{0}|\\
&<\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{x_{0}}}\cdot\dfrac{3\sqrt{x_{0}}}{2}\cdot\epsilon\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

In order to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{x_0}$$

Note that  for large enough $ n$, we have $$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x_0}|=\frac {|x_n -x_0|}{|\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x_0}|}\le$$

$$\frac {|x_n -x_0|}{(3/2) \sqrt{x_0}} <\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

An option for $x \ge 0. $

$f(x) =√x$ is continuos at $x_0 \gt 0.$

$\iff$

For every sequence $x_n , x_n \ge 0$ ,  with

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n=x_0$ we have:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=f(x_0).$

Show that $f$ is continuos at $x_0 \gt 0$ using $\epsilon,\delta$ definition.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta <\epsilon √x_o$, then

$|x-x_0|\lt \delta$ implies

$|√x-√x_0| = $

$\dfrac {|x-x_0|}{√x+√x_0}\lt \dfrac{\delta}{√x_0}= \epsilon.$